# How do I stop Google Scripts from asking the creator for permission to access the creator's files

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script

I have a script that I created for a google sheet that is used as a template.  I copy the template, but the copied google sheet requests access every time (it's requesting I grant access to my files I am the creator of the script and the user on Workspace).  I found it has something to do with the default project setting because I created a new project and if that project id is on the script it asked me the first time and never again.

When I copy the template sheet it is not copying the newly created project id in the script.  I either need to figure out how to stop the default script project from requiring authentication or set the have the new project ID copy over automatically.

Comment: Does changing the project ID of a newly-copied version of the Sheet stop it from asking for permission or does it still ask?

Comment: Yes, if I manually add the project id it no longer asks permission to gain access to my own files.  It's as if the system default project id doesn't recognize me as me but when I create a project ID it does.